# What is the file size limitation for a XAML Binding to an BitmapSource?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, binding

What is the maximum size for a XAML Binding to an image source? I can't find any information in the microsoft documentation but there has to be a limitation.

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyLargeBitmapSource}" />
```

This works fine most of the time, but as soon as the file size becomes very large, some strange behavior occurs. The most common phenomenon is that the image is simply not displayed.

Example:

- Image with 376222kb **is not** displayed
- Image with 190327kb **is** displayed

The only limitation i found does not match my images:

> The maximum height and width of an image is 2^16 pixels at 32 bits per channel * 4 channels. The maximum size of a BitmapSource is 2^32 bytes (64 gigabytes) and the maximum image size is four gigapixels. The minimum image size is 1x1.

Found at Microsoft [BitmapSource Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource?view=netcore-3.1)

So i guess there has to be a limitation for the file size of the image or a limitation on the binding "byte" size? What could cause this issue to occour?

Comment: When debugging, do you notice an exception? Is there a difference whan your application runs as 64 bit app?

Comment: What type is the MyLargeBitmapSource property? What if you explicitly create a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame from the image file?

Comment: @KlausGütter Datatype is BitmapImage. It throws an exception no matter if i assign StreamSource or uriSource. The exception is: The value does not have to be negative and less than or equal to the Int32.MaxValue. Parameter name: pressure
How should an 367megabyte image exceed the int32.maxvalue?

Comment: @Clemens even if i set this image directly like Source ="376222kb.jpg" then this exception appears. it looks like the data gets converted anyway and exceeds the limits. But i cant figure out what causes the bytes to exceed Int32.MaxValue

Comment: You are perhaps confusing the file size with the maximum width or height. The size roughly counts the number of bytes in an encoded bitmap frame, which is usually far less than the number of bytes of the decoded raw pixel buffer - which is width * height * bytes-per-pixel.

Comment: @Clemens yes you are absolutely right. that also explains the inconsistency as well. i guess there is no real way to check weather i can convert an image selected by the user beforehand? Or is there a way to handle such large image files?